# JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: D:\XamppInstalation\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld2\sql\mysql\updates

Tags: module, installation, error-warning

I followed the tutorial on the Joomla website about [Creating a simple module/Using the Database](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Using_the_Database).
I created the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Mod_Helloworld2</name>
    <author>Dhany</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>Hello World 2 with database</description>
    <files>
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <filename>mod_helloworld2.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_helloworld2">mod_helloworld2.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helper2.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
    </config>


    <install>
         <sql>
             <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
         </sql>
    </install>

    <uninstall>
         <sql>
             <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
         </sql>
    </uninstall>

    <update> 
        <schemas>
            <schemapath type="mysql">sql/mysql/updates</schemapath> 
        </schemas> 
    </update>
</extension>
```

I installed this module and successfully, but it gives me the following warning:

> JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: D:\XamppInstalation\htdocs\joomla\modules\mod_helloworld2\sql\mysql\updates

I checked my Module inside Zip File, `sql\mysql\updates` folder does exists, but when I checked within the installed module this folder doesn't exist.

This is my [zipped module](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zadX9ZteP2NoCHOfsxaf4cyi4JgcEER_/view?usp=sharing).

Please help me check if there is something wrong with my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updates` folder is empty. Empty folders are not created during installation. You don't need to add update schema paths in the initial version of your extension since it's going to be empty. But if you want to include it anyways, create a dummy file like `index.html` inside the folder.

Comment: That's works... thank you

Comment: @dhany please award the green tick to this answer so that the site stops bumping it to the top of the answer list.